# shared_ptr : allocation without instanciation

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, new-operator, circular-dependency

I am working in a code where I have to manage a terrific design.

The problem I encounter now is a circular dependency between two classes : the class A needs the class B to be instanciated, and the class B need a `shared_ptr` to the class A to be instanciated. And A is built by a class C, which inherits of B... So C passes `*this` to A's constructor to build it. Yes, I know, it is horrible. But I can't change that (there are more classes than A, B, and C...).

Nevertheless, I try to separate all these classes in order to be able to test them (today, thay are all tested in one block in one test class).

For the tests, I tried to consider only the classes A and B, not C.

I tried to use `operator new` to allocate memory for A without building any object (because I need B...). Then I build a `shared_ptr` to A from this allocated memory, and build B by passing this `shared_ptr`.
Now I have instanciated B, I can pass it to A to instanciate it with the placement new, by using `shared_ptr::get()`.

It does compile. But somewhere in the A instanciation, the `shared_ptr` with a pointer allocated but without any object is copied by one of its parent class, and I get a crash in `shared_ptr` (destructor).

I guess it is beacause of the assigment, but I Don't understand why. Before asking you what could be the cause of this crash, I'd like to know ifyou think using `operator new` and then placement news makes sense in my use case.
Thanks.

Here is a pice of code bout this memory management :

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
 
struct Class_A
{
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
};

int main()
{
    void *rawMemory = operator new(sizeof(Class_A));
 
    std::shared_ptr<Class_A> foo1 = std::make_shared<Class_A>();
    
    std::shared_ptr<Class_A> foo2(static_cast<Class_A*>(rawMemory));
 
    std::cout << foo2->a << std::endl;
    std::cout << foo2->b << std::endl;
 
    foo1 = foo2;
 
    new (foo2.get()) Class_A();
 
    std::cout << foo2->a << std::endl;
    std::cout << foo2->b << std::endl;
 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using `placement new` is basically saying, "I'm doing something very weird, unusual, or as a hack".  Consider using `weak_ptr` or just a raw pointer to get around the circular reference issue.  Whichever class instance is expected to "outlive" the other class gets a shared_ptr to the other class instance.  The class that is expected to be destructed first just needs a raw pointer back to the other class.  You can also use `weak_ptr`, but if your object lifetime between objects is guaranteed, you can get away with raw pointer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

In my code, to do the `operator new`, I passed to the `sizeof()` a `decltype` of a variable. But if was a `decltype` of the `shared_ptr`, instead of the element type. So I got a crash with the error :
`free(): invalid size`

I now use `decltype(myVariable)::element_type`, and it does work.

So the sample code is finally a "good" hack, if you cannot change bad conception of legacy code.